# Is a very long alphabetic password harder to crack than a shorter password with special characters?

Tags: cryptography, computer-science

Is it true that a password consisting of the alphabet, even of common known names is much harder to find for a computer program than a short password, even though it uses numbers and other characters?

Is `Tr0ub4dor&3` harder to find than `correct horse battery staple`?

I would be greatful for a detailed answer, one a computational thinker would understand. Below is a visualisation of what I mean. I such is true I feel I am not the only one who will have to rethink his password strategy.

[image: security]

Comment: No.  It simply depends on the size of the total space of possible passwords.

Comment: What don't you understand about the XKCD comic? It shows, fairly accurately, how guessable each password is. Are you having trouble understanding why Tr0ub4dor&3 only has 28 bits of entropy while correct horse battery staple had 44?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure cryptography or information security.

Answer (score 2):

By assigning 11 bits of entropy to each word, the pass phrase implies that each was chosen randomly from a list of 2048 words. This is a relatively short list; you could think of it as the 2000 most common nouns. If four such words are chosen *at random*, any one of the 2<sup>44</sup> possible phrases is equally likely.

The base word "troubador" is allowed more entropy (16 bits) because presumably it was chosen at random from a larger dictionary of "uncommon words". If you had a dictionary of about 65,000 such words, and chose one at random, this would be a fair guess. The rest of the entropy are based on reasonable estimates: Is a common transform applied to the character, or not? One bit apiece; randomly pick a digit: 3 bits; etc.

However, the important thing to understand is that the length of the word "troubador" doesn't really matter. Because it's a dictionary word, what matters is how many words are in the dictionary. If you give me the letters "tr  b d r", I can easily guess the rest. Individual letters are only unpredictable if they are chosen randomly. If you use words, then you have to consider entire words to be the letters of your alphabet.

But even a huge dictionary of real words is only going to be on the order a few hundred thousand, about 18–19 bits of entropy per word. That's why you need to pick multiple words for a passphrase, or give up words and pick letters, numbers, and symbols randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a visual comparison of the two approaches. This is the number of possible passwords as you increase the alphabet size given a fixed password length:

[image: pass2]

And this is when you increase the password length given a fixed alphabet size:

[image: alpha2]

Comment: But that's not what the OP is comparing.  "correcthorsebatterystaple" is in fact length = 4, alphabet-size = 10k (or so).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth With an entropy of 11 bits, the alphabet is 2048, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is correct for a brute force attack on a password. A brute-force attack is repeatedly try guesses for the password and is trying all available combinations.

However in reality attacks are more often dictionary attacks. This means the software tries to determine the password by trying hundreds or sometimes millions of likely possibilities, such as words in a dictionary.

So a long alphabetic password can be hard to crack when using brute-force but still easy to crack with a dictionary attack.

Answer (score 0):

> The maths in the comic are correct, but the important point is that
>   good passwords must be both hard to guess and easy to remember. The
>   main message of the comic is to show that common "password generation
>   rules" fail at both points: they make hard to remember passwords,
>   which are nonetheless not that hard to guess.
>
> It also illustrates the failure of human minds at evaluating security.
>   "Tr0ub4dor&3" looks more randomish than "correcthorsebatterystaple";
>   and the same minds will give good points to the latter only because of
>   the wrong reason, i.e. the widespread (but misguided) belief that
>   password length makes strength. It does not. A password is not strong
>   because it is long; it is strong because it includes a lot of
>   randomness (all the entropy bits we have been discussing all along).
>   Extra length just allows for more strength, by giving more room for
>   randomness; in particular, by allowing "gentle" randomness that is
>   easy to remember, like the electric horse thing. On the other hand, a
>   very short password is necessarily weak, because there is only so much
>   entropy you can fit in 5 characters.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase